# Error: unexpected '}' in "}" if...print()...else...print()

Tags: r, if-statement

I WAS GIVEN ANSWER: THE if's closing BRACKET should be BEFORE ELSE not ABOVE.

This error had already been discussed here:
[Error: unexpected '}' in " }"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264905/error-unexpected-in) and 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303559/error-unexpected-in
But they do not help me.

I run the code:

```
i <- 21
if(i==22){
 print(c("xxx"))
}
else{
 print(c("yyy"))
}
```

And get an error

> else{
>   **Error: unexpected 'else' in "else"**
>     print(c("yyy"))
>   [1] "yyy"
>   }
>   **Error: unexpected '}' in "}"**

I use Rstudio on Windows, quite new R version and Rstudio, but not sure where to check it

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Is that all the code, one of the reasons you can get this error is something unbalanced before it.

Comment: Hey, what happen to my "Closing Hammer of Thor"? Did I run out of lightening?

Comment: @BondedDust - the same has happened to me!

Comment: Maybe they will recharge our hammers later?

Comment: @BondedDust, i think it temporary for testing purposes, but can't find now where i saw it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the else after `if`s bracket

```
i <- 21
if(i==22){
  print(c("xxx"))
}else{
  print(c("yyy"))
}

##[1] "yyy"
```

Comment: From the ?"if" help page: In particular, you should not have a newline between } and else to avoid a syntax error in entering a if ... else construct at the keyboard or via source. For that reason, one (somewhat extreme) attitude of defensive programming is to always use braces, e.g., for if clauses

Answer (score 0):

This code will work in a function or when enclosed in braces, but not elsewhere because `else` is on a new line. See the duplicate question for more details.

Good practice is to put the `else` on the same line as the `}`. Then it will work for both.

Comment: What gives you the impression that the code will work in a script?

Comment: I was sure that it would but tried it and was shocked to see that it  doesn't! Apparently this is a misunderstanding I've had for a long time; thanks for setting me straight!

Comment: I figured out my misunderstanding though -- it will work in a function and I guess I thought the same rules applied when running as a script. Editing response...